# Consulta porque no puedo cargar el archivo con la funcion glob.glob, no se porque no lo encuentra

Tags: variables-globales, maxima, os

try:
ruta = max(glob.glob(f'input/{grupo_corporativo}/*.xlsx'), key=os.path.getctime)
logging.info('Se encontró planilla de afiliados en ' + ruta)
except Exception as err:
logging.critical(f'No se encontró planilla de afiliados en input/{grupo_corporativo}/*.xlsx: {err}')
exit()

error:
No se encontró planilla de afiliados en input/moa/*.: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Pero, ¿Qué hiciste?, preguntas así corren con el riesgo de ser cerradas y/o eliminadas pues no cumplen con los lineamientos del sitio, te recomiendo leer el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/525241/edit) tu pregunta y añadir lo que hace falta incluyendo [un ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de código de lo que hiciste.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.